# How to search for the Unicode Text when using the Uiautomator to do android automated testing?

Tags: android, unicode, android-uiautomator

I search for a long time to know how to use the Uiautomator tools to  set the search criteria to match the Unicode Text (for example:chinese).

```
UiScrollable languageItemScrol = new UiScrollable( new UiSelector().scrollable(true));  
UiObject languageItemOption = languageItemScrol.getChildByText(  
                new UiSelector().text("中文 (简体)"), "中文 (简体)", true);  
languageItemOption.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Yes, I usually test android terminal in different languages， I have to know how to use the Uiautomator testing in variety of  languages;

Would you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
UiScrollable languageItemScrol = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
UiSelector selector = new UiSelector().text("中文 (简体)");
languageItemScrol.scrollIntoView(selector);
languageItemScrol.getChildByInstance(selector, 0).clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

From javadoc of the getChildByText():

```
/**
  * Searches for a child element in the present scrollable container. The
  * search first looks for a child element that matches the
  * selector you provided, then looks for the text in its children elements.
  * If both search conditions are fulfilled, the method returns a {@ link UiObject}
  * representing the element matching the selector (not the child element in its
  * subhierarchy containing the text).
  */
```

In your code the text "中文 (简体)" is first searched, then it's children are searched for text "中文 (简体)" also. I think this is the reason your code does not work.

Hope this helps.